# InvalidVersionSpecError : Invalid version spec: =2.7

Tags: python-3.x, conda, anaconda3, conda-forge

[Getting the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z14D4.png)

I am working on a high performance cluster. Therefore, need solutions with respect to that

I tried updating conda, by creating a new env with python 3.9 and conda version 4.5.11.
But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try building the environment with Python 3.10.x as Python 3.9 sometimes gives these errors.